# Log4j ни как не хочет писать trace

Tags: java, log4j

Log4j ни как не хочет писать trace.
Я уже использую их API для настроек логов:

```
ConfigurationBuilder< BuiltConfiguration > builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
         builder.setStatusLevel( org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.ALL);
         builder.setConfigurationName("RollingBuilder");
         // create a console appender
         AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE").addAttribute("target",
             ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
         appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
             .addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable"));
         builder.add( appenderBuilder );
         // create the new logger
         builder.add( builder.newLogger( "TestLogger", org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.ALL )
             .add( builder.newAppenderRef( "rolling" ) )
             .addAttribute( "additivity", false ) );
         builder.add( builder.newRootLogger( org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.ALL )
             .add( builder.newAppenderRef( "rolling" ) ) );
         LoggerContext ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
         logger.debug("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
         logger.trace("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
```

и все равно пишется только debug.
Что не так?
Вот мой помник, взят с сайта slf4j:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.10</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency> 
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.28</version>
</dependency>
<dependency> 
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.28</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Покажите как создаете `logger`

Comment: private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WindowFunction.class);

Answer (score 0):

получилось добиться появления trace в логах с помощью такой штуки:

```
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger rootLogger = 
(ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger)LoggerFactory.
getLogger(ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
   
rootLogger.setLevel(ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.TRACE);
```

решение так себе, но другого пока что найти не смог

Comment: Это значит, что у вас не используется log4j, а используется logback. Для него задавайте конфигурацию в файле `logback.xml` как описано тут http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Comment: помник выложил, по другому у меня не работал лог

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что у вас добавлено две реализации логирования: `log4j` и `logback`. При этом `slf4j` выбрал из них одну.

Если хотите использовать именно `log4j`, то уберите из pom зависимость на `logback`.

Comment: Ну так сообщение и говорит о том, что log4j не сконфигурирован, т.е. slf4j использует log4j, но нет правильной конфигурации log4j. Если вы добавляете logback, то в этом случае slf4j используе logback, а не log4j и то, что вы пробуете конфигурировать log4j не работает. Если вы хотите использовать log4j, то нужно убрать logback и сконфигурировать именно log4j.

Comment: убрал logback, log4j заработал, проблема была в том, что он выдает только error, поэтому сразу не заметил, я дебаг и инфо пробовал. Вот только вопрос с конфигурацией остался открытым. Я ее уже и в ресурсы и в корень и т.д. кидаю, а он все равно ее не видит